# HP Z Station - Win10 - Anaconda Rstudio - Issue with Saving R Script

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio

I bought an HP Z Station with Win10, turned off all anti virus software, and loaded Anaconda.  I then created an environment with RStudio/R.

Launched R Studio, create an R Script with many lines of R code and it runs and saves without issue, but the size of the R script file is 0 KB.  After closing the R Script, then reopening the R script, there isn't any of the R code that I saved.

I have saved the R Script to different locations on the drive, but same result as above.

Answer (score 0):

At issue was the encodings.

I navigated to: Tools\Global Options\Code\Saving\Default Encoding

There I selected, UTF-8